# Raphael.js map set get an element by title

Tags: javascript, attributes, raphael

I have a map set and am using Raphael.js and all is well but I'm struggling to work out the method of locating an element within the set via a given title.

I'm initiating as follows.

```
var MAP_WIDTH  = 600;
var MAP_HEIGHT = 600;
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map");
var map = new Raphael(mapContainer, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT)
var group = map.set();

var regions = {};
var regions =  [
 { 'title': "One", 'path': "m651.845 1021.74c-51.0321,-190.505 52.8953,-258.102 -72.0694,-253.37"},
 { 'title': "Two", 'path': "m534.899 632.399c-170.109,0.209524 -108.157,-95.2197 -331.825,-233.531"},
 { 'title': "Three", 'path': "m581.183 601.967c187.821,-0.668381 65.1258,-112.492 192.735,-339.055"}
]
```

Then I push to the set as follows.

```
regions.forEach(function(region){
    group.push(
        map.path(region.path).attr({
         'title':region.title,
         'stroke':"#FF0000",
         'fill':"#FFFFFF"
        })
    );
}
```

On a click or mouseover event I would like to be able to target a specific element, in other words, a click will alter the fill of element titled 'One' (this is regardless of whether 'One' was clicked so 'this' is not the solution). I can do it via group[0] but I may not know the index of the item I'm searching for.

How do I target the specific element within the group with title 'One'?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way by title, so I would probably store the reference somewhere for access later. Eg you could store in a element.data() method, a reference to the object you want to act on later.

Comment: Thanks Ian, will look at that for now as will certainly work whilst seeing if there's an actual method within Raphael

Comment: Btw if you are able to use Snap.svg (Raphaels sister library, a lot is the same code and methods, but it's a bit more modern), you can use css selectors to find elements which may help.

Comment: yes I only just started looking at Raphael but have now noticed Snap so will check it out - thx