# How to identify individual path objects in raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be simple, but I don't know how and I'm not sure if I can describe it correctly.  I've tried searching and haven't found quite what I'm looking for.  I've drawn a series of hexagons in raphael.js.  Each one has a title so displays coordinates when I hover over the element, but setting an id attribute doesn't seem to work.  I need to know which object the mouse is over and set up a click function based on that information.  I tried getting the number of children for the DIV in which the paper resides, but I only get one, which I kind of expected, the single SVG.  I don't know how to get the number of children within that SVG or how to identify which one I'm trying to select.  When clicked, I need to create a new element in a different DIV, based on the properties of the object I clicked.  It's basically a map grid for which I need to create a zoomed-in version of that hexagon.

Comment: Firstly I would migrate to Snap.svg which is Raphaels later incarnation (its pretty much backwards compatible). If you can't, maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228227/raphael-js-map-set-get-an-element-by-title would help